# ng-repeat with as alias not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

According to [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) this directive should work: `user in users | filter:search as searchResults`. But it does only if I remove `as`, but I need it to show empty results message. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hedgic/9yHjj/81/) to demonstrate.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `as` syntax is not available in your version of angular, try one of the unstable releases. Also having the condition in the loop will prevent it from being visible. Try this instead (with the latest unstable release *v1.3.0-beta.17*):

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
  <div ng-repeat="user in users | filter:search as searchResults">
    <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
    <div>{{user.description}}</div>
  </div>

  <!-- move this out of the loop -->
  <div ng-if="searchResults.length == 0">
    Nothing found
  </div>
</div>
```

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/pobafecu/1/